# How to solve this problem with Gurobi add-in Opensolver excel

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, solver, gurobi

My main problem is that, when I try to solve an optimization using Gurobi with the OpenSolver add-in, I get the error that there is no feasible solution.

To summarize, my variable $X_i$ has a maximum value $H$ and it is a storage filling problem.

The objetive function is to minimize the cost of filling:

$$Min \sum_{i=0}^n X_i*C_i $$

With certain constrains that indicates  what are the maximun and minimum levels in certain dates.
$X_i$ can be:
$\le 0$ or $\ge 0$, if it is lower than 0 you are selling your material, if it is higher than 0 you are injecting, so, you can buy and sell in order to minimize the cost.

$H$ must be the minimum between a constant and a function that depends on the sum up to $X_i-1$.

$$H = \text{min}\{\text{Constant}, f(V_i-1)\}$$
$$V_i-1= \text{Filling of day} D-1$$

When I put the constraints separately (TEST):

$X_i \le Constant$ --> OK, I get a solution.

$X_i \le f(V_i-1)$ --> OK, I get a solution.

$X_i \le \text{Constant1}$ **and** $X_i \le Constant2$ --> OK, I get a solution.

*BUT: When I put my real problem:*

$X_i \le Constant1$ **and** $X_i \le f(V_i-1)$ --> **NOT OK, it doesn't give me a solution.**

Comment: You mean $X_i\le Constant$ not $X_i<Constant$, right?  (I presume all of your constraints are actually not strict inequalities, right?)

Comment: Yes, you are right sorry Xi <= Constant

Comment: @ADMGYP, Would you please, elaborate a bit more on the problem you are facing? What is the objective function and its direction? 
The first and the third constraints you mentioned are actually the bound and can be omitted. Is the $\text{f}$ function convex or non-convex?

Comment: @A.Omidi I have made some fixes, I hope it can be solved.
The restrictions are actually tests I have done, the real restriction is the 4th one.